# Required rule in Laravel 10 always fails even if fields are present

Tags: php, laravel, validation, post

I'm building an API using laravel framework, I defined this route:

```
Route::controller(AuthenticationController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('/signUp', 'signUp');
});
```

with this function in the `AuthenticationController`:

```
public function signUp(SignUpRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
```

and this is the code of `SignUpRequest`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SignUpRequest extends BaseRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "email" => "required|email",
            "firstname" => "required|string|max:50",
            "lastname" => "required|string|max:50",
            "image" => "string|image",
            "password" => "required|string|min:8|max:100",
            "confirmPassword" => "required|string|same:password"
        ];
    }
}
```

When using postman to send a request to this route I get error saying that the email field is required (and all other fields)

The fields are present in the request's body

```
{
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "fname",
    "image": null,
    "lastname": "lname",
    "password": "password",
    "confirmPassword": "password",
}
```

I don't understand why is this error occurring let alone how to solve it, can anyone help ?

The error message

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "The email field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "firstname": [
            "The firstname field is required."
        ],
        "lastname": [
            "The lastname field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ],
        "confirmPassword": [
            "The confirm password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the required rule and error didn't occur, but still I don't understand the reason of this behavior.

**EDIT**
these are screenshots from postman
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbXfr.png)

[body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE2l0.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are sending that postman request as JSON and not anything else?

Comment: Instead of `dd($request)`, try `dd(request()->input())`; do you see `['email' => 'example@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'fname', ...]`? Or, one-by-one, `dd(request()->input('email'))`. Your request _looks_ ok, but there might be something off if validation is failing.

Comment: @matiaslauriti
yes, i'm using `Content-Type:application/json` header in the request

Comment: @TimLewis the dd is not getting executed, I tried `dd(request()->input());` anyway but still the same results

Comment: Then your `FormRequest` validation is happening before that `dd()` is hit. You can either move that `dd()` statement into your `SignUpRequest` (i.e. in the `authorize()` method), or temporarily change your code to `public function singup(Request $request) { dd(...); }`.

Comment: @TimLewis I changed `SignUpRequest` to `Request`, with `dd($request()->input())` I got an empty array so I tried `dd($request)`, I see this ```content: """
    {
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "firstname": "fname",
        "image": null,
        "lastname": "lname",
        "password": "password",
        "confirmPassword": "password",
    }
    """
``` 
in the dd result

Comment: So yeah, the issue seems to be how you're sending your request from Postman; it's not populating the request body properly for `request()->input()` (and by extension, `request()->input('email')`) to detect it, so your validation is failing on all the `required` checks. Sidenote, I never do `dd(request())`; there's generally too much information to show properly, which is why I suggest `request()->input()` or similar. Can you show your Postman request? Probably as a screenshot would be best.

Comment: I edited the question and added the screenshots, the content-type header is overwritten by application/json  (not shown in the screenshot)

Comment: I found the problem, I just notices that extra comma at the end of confirmPassword line, Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Ah ha, yeah, that would do it; if your JSON is invalid, then nothing gets sent, and JSON indeed does not allow training commas. Glad you got it working!